# Passing parameters to BizTalk xslt map

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-2016

Is it possible to pass some parameters to xslt map? Let's say I have the usual btm and xslt maps and going to use it with usual receive/send ports. And I want my xslt map to depend on some external flags - if when map is starting it receives flag1=1, one transformation is performed, if it receives flag1=0, another one is performed. Is it possible?

Of course, I can simply create two different maps. I also understand that if I put my map inside an orchestration, somehow I can pass variables when orchestration is calling map. But is it possible to have a sort of choose-when that depends on external flags within one map and, the most important thing, to set up these flags in BizTalk Server Administration Console, when I set up ports and maps binding, NOT to hardcode it in orchestration?

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Have you looked at using the BRE Engine?

Comment: Thanks for response. No I haven't yet, but I will. But I've read some documentation today so let me specify my question: is it possible from custom xslt to access property of custom pipeline component (I'll create component and add to pipeline used in receive location) OR from custom xslt to access message context (I mean that I can change message context at pipeline level according to pipeline properties and, for example, to add to context a sort of flag - if somehow I can access message context from xslt after adding a flag at pipeline level probably it will solve my problem)? Thanks.

Comment: There was a Context Accessor functoid that was on Codeplex, you can stil download the archive from there.  https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=contextaccessor

Answer (score 0):

You can use external data(maybe a sys var or table data) by calling a c# heper, but there is no way to setup a flag from Biztalk  Console Admin